# How to allow oracle database to be accessed remotely?

Tags: oracle

I have oracle database installed on one machine, I am trying to accessing the same from other machine. I tried via Oracle SQL developer eclipse, and even via JDBC program, nothing works.  I am not sure if it is firewall issue(I have ruled out this because both the machines are in same domain) or something to do with **Oracle database setting**. I know in MySQL you need to grant permission to connect to database remotely. Do we need to set something similar on oracle SID also?

More details on the error message i get: Io Exception: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: This is a database admin question. Try http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks for the site details..

Comment: Which JDBC client were you using? Do you have the Oracle Client installed? If you have the Oracle client installed, have you tried tnsping?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a listener running for the Oracle database?  It has to be accepting requests before you can connect to it.  Check in `$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin`  see if there's a file called `listener.ora`.  That's the first step.

If there is, check the status of the listener.  From the command line, logged in as oracle, enter:

```
lsnrctl status
```

If you set a series of messages that look like this:

```
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
TNS-00511: No listener
Solaris Error: 146: Connection refused
```

then the listener isn't started.  In that case, start the listener:

```
lsnrctl start
```

Then try to connect again.

Comment: i have checked the status, looks like it is up. Message I am getting: Service "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "orcl", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully